# How to write a screen clearance script?

Tags: bash, scripts, graphics, screensaver

**We are producing a terminal display (kiosk mode), Ubuntu 16.04, once a day we want to:**

- set all pixels on screen to white for 10 seconds
- set all pixels on screen to black for 10 seconds
- set the screen to „energy save mode“ for 30 seconds (so that it somewhat dims, backlight off...)

(makebelieve or reality, we think, that will make our screens live longer )

#### Are there screen-commands to achieve this?

(So I pack them into a shell script and set up a daily cron job…)

Comment: What are "screen-commands"? You don't mean GNU screen, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found everything I need:**
(with [xbacklight](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xbacklight) being one more, not yet tested option)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

xset +dpms
xset dpms force standby
sleep 1
xset dpms force suspend
sleep 1
xset dpms force off
sleep 1
xset dpms force on
sleep 1

#xrandr -q | grep "connected"
xrandr --output HDMI1 --brightness 0.2
sleep 2
xrandr --output HDMI1 --brightness 1.0

xset s noblank
/usr/bin/xsetroot -solid Black
xset s activate
sleep 1
xset s activate
sleep 1

xset dpms force on
/usr/bin/xsetroot -solid Green
xset s activate
sleep 1

xset dpms force on
/usr/bin/xsetroot -solid White
xset s activate
sleep 1

xset s off
xset dpms force on
```